# How to create a key value pair from two values

Tags: javascript, database, key-value, key-value-store

I'm returning key-value fields from the database, how do merge the two values into a new key-value pair?

```
{
  "conditions": [{
        "key": "target_condition",
        "value": "100"
    },
    {
        "key": "target_count_or_value",
        "value": "value"
    }
  ]
}
```

How to:

```
{
"conditions": {
    "target_condition": "110",
    "target_count_or_value": "quantity" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
data.conditions = data.conditions.map(item=>{[item.key]: item.value})
```

this uses the map function and dynamic object keys to build new objects

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right direction.

Comment: This will throw an error as the `{}` is treated as a code block in `item => {}`, not an object. OP also wants an object to be set for `conditions`, and not an array which is what you're currently trying to set `conditions` to.